# WSO2 API Manager Analytics doesn't works

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

the wso2 API Manager it's working normaly but the analytics inside the wso2-am and the product wso2-am Analytics doesn't works

I execute all the steps describes in the documentation of the wso2-apim Analytics (Quick Setup and
Standard Setup) but nothing works.

when I was configuring the Enterprise Integrator the analytics has'nt work but when I configured the "synapse.properties" file the analytics started to work normaly.

it's important to know that the wso2-ei, wso2-am and wso2-am Analytics is running in the same machine.

- Enterprise Integrator offset = 0
- API Manager Offset = 4
- API Manager Analytics - Offset = 5

the documentation of **WSO2 Administration Guide** "Default Ports of WSO2 Products" it is a folow description:
for API Manager:

- 7711 + Port offset of the APIM Analytics Server - Thrift SSL port for secure transport when publishing analytics to the API Manager Analytics server.

for Enterprise Integrator:

- 7712 - Thrift SSL port for secure transport, where the client is authenticated to DAS

I verifyed the log file "wso2server.log" of the wso2-am and I see the folow error:

- ERROR - Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
- ERROR - Thrift exception

I don't know if the fact of the wso2-am Analytics isn't work it's related to the error showing in the log of the wso2-am.

someone can help me to make the wso2-am Analytics works normaly?

Comment: 2 questions. 1) you've just wrote yourself that the analytics server is running on offset 5 (7711+5=7716 and 7712+5=7717) and the wso2am is still trying to connect to 7711/7712. You can update the ports and auth in the  config file. 2) are you aware that analytics  for esb and am are different? do you have both bundles deployed on DAS?

Comment: @gusto2 1) Yes, that's what a wrote. What config file are you talking about? because there is several. 2) Yes, I am aware. There is two DAS, one for wso2ei, that it's install with the package of the wso2-ei 6.1.1 (ESB, business process,  broker and analytics). The other works with the wso2am 2.1.0 and it's separated product and need to be installed separated (wso2am-analytics-2.1.0) and aparently works only with the wso2-am.

Comment: `What config file are you talking about?` all AM related ports are defined in the `api-manager.xml `, have a look under the Analytics section

Comment: @gusto2  I already configured this section (<Enabled>true</Enabled>) including the folowing part (<DASServerURL>{tcp://localhost:7612}</DASServerURL>). in this case, I already tried leaving it the way it is and tried with offset 5 and even then the error continues. I don't know if this configuration is related with the fact that the wso2am-analytics it's not reporting anything

Comment: `is related with the fact that the wso2am-analytics it's not reporting` indeed, if the wso2am isn't sending anything, thw analytics won't show any data

Comment: I created an API that is used in a web page that is calling the API several times with different parameters, also I am making the request of the token passing user and password and all this it's working normally